# Passing array of strings as character pointers

Tags: c, string

I have been trying to pass an array of string to a function. Although i know of other processes of doing it, i specifically want to know exactly why this particular code isn't working

I have tried in the following manner

```
#include<stdio.h>

void check_number(char* str[])
{
    int sum=0;
    int i=0;
    while(str[0][i]!='/0')
    {
        char a='a';
        sum=sum+str[0][i]-(int)(a);
    }
    printf("number = %d ",sum);
}

int main()
{
    char* str[2];
    printf("Enter a string ");
    scanf("%s",str[0]);

    printf("Enter a string ");
    scanf("%s",str[1]);

    check_number(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Problem 1: You haven't allocated any memory for `str[0]` and `str[1]` to point to. Problem 2: `check_number()` has no way to know how many strings you've handed it.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the issue in the posted code, here

```
char* str[2];
```

`str` is **array of two character pointer** i.e `str[0]` and `str[1]` are character pointers i.e they need to initialize with valid address but you haven't allocated memory for them.

```
scanf("%s",str[0]); /* No memory allocated for str[0] */
scanf("%s",str[1]); /* No memory allocated for str[1] */
```

You need to allocate memory for `str[0]` & `str[1]` before scanning data into it. for e.g

```
int main(void)
{
    char* str[2];
    for(int i = 0; i < 2 ; i++) {
        printf("Enter a string ");
        str[i] = malloc(MAX_BUF_SIZE); /*define this macro for no of bytes */
        scanf("%s",str[i]);
    }
    /* do some stuff */
    /* free dynamically allocated memory for each str[index] */
    return 0;
}
```

Another problem is here

```
while(str[0][i]!='\0') { /* '/0' --> '\0' */
    char a='a';
    sum=sum+str[0][i]-(int)(a); /* what you want to achieve here, please explain */
}
```

when this loop is going to terminate ? There should be a loop terminating condition else it will loop infinitely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have noticed that every time i try to build a 2d array of strings and pass it in a function i come up with unknown pointer problems. Is there a simpler approach in which i can do it so that i dont mess up?

Comment: @user11848049 what exactly `check_number()` for ? Please add input and expected output in question by editing it.

Comment: Actually its an incomplete code. This function is basically to convert strings to integers

Comment: I will be checking for null. If there is null we know the string has ended

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
char* str[2];
```

declares an array of 2 pointers to `char`, but the pointers do not point to valid memory. You need to reserve/allocate some space somewhere.

One possible solution is to simply have two independent buffers in the stack:

```
const size_t bufferSize = 100;
char str1[bufferSize];
char str2[bufferSize];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have noticed that every time i try to build a 2d array of strings and pass it in a function i come up with unknown pointer problems. Is there a simpler approach in which i can do it so that i dont mess up?